# R : How can I combine these two data frames into a data frame by date column?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I'm new practicing R and now getting stuck with problems for many days can't go on.
I chose my recorded data to analyse. The data will be recorded every hour from 2 example devices and there are some little delay problem between recording devices to database server so some hours the data can be recorded at the seconds '0 (+-5 or keep changing a very little unstably)' you can clearly see in example data.

Big problems are

1) There are some rows from Date column are not equal in seconds part.

2) There are some rows from Date are missing rows I found a missing row from df2 'at hour 13' after I had selected example data by head(df1,24)/head(df2,24) and got the results like under here. If there are 10000 selected rows going to be a big problem with many missing values.

```
> class(df1$Date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

df1

```
> df1
                  Date Val   Weekday
1  2017-06-08 13:00:04 520  Thursday
2  2017-06-08 12:00:04 507  Thursday
3  2017-06-08 11:00:04 501  Thursday
4  2017-06-08 10:00:04 472  Thursday
5  2017-06-08 09:00:04 444  Thursday
6  2017-06-08 08:00:04 446  Thursday
7  2017-06-08 07:00:04 444  Thursday
8  2017-06-08 06:00:04 441  Thursday
9  2017-06-08 05:00:04 439  Thursday
10 2017-06-08 04:00:04 442  Thursday
11 2017-06-08 03:00:04 440  Thursday
12 2017-06-08 02:00:04 443  Thursday
13 2017-06-08 01:00:04 445  Thursday
14 2017-06-08 00:00:04 445  Thursday
15 2017-06-07 23:00:04 446 Wednesday
16 2017-06-07 22:00:04 445 Wednesday
17 2017-06-07 21:00:04 447 Wednesday
18 2017-06-07 20:00:04 445 Wednesday
19 2017-06-07 19:00:04 451 Wednesday
20 2017-06-07 18:00:04 469 Wednesday
21 2017-06-07 17:00:04 473 Wednesday
22 2017-06-07 16:00:04 510 Wednesday
23 2017-06-07 15:00:04 517 Wednesday
24 2017-06-07 14:00:04 524 Wednesday
```

df2

```
> df2
                  Date df1.Val   Weekday
1  2017-06-08 12:00:04 507  Thursday
2  2017-06-08 11:00:04 501  Thursday
3  2017-06-08 10:00:04 472  Thursday
4  2017-06-08 09:00:04 444  Thursday
5  2017-06-08 08:00:04 446  Thursday
6  2017-06-08 07:00:04 444  Thursday
7  2017-06-08 06:00:04 441  Thursday
8  2017-06-08 05:00:04 439  Thursday
9  2017-06-08 04:00:04 442  Thursday
10 2017-06-08 03:00:04 440  Thursday
11 2017-06-08 02:00:04 443  Thursday
12 2017-06-08 01:00:04 445  Thursday
13 2017-06-08 00:00:04 445  Thursday
14 2017-06-07 23:00:04 446 Wednesday
15 2017-06-07 22:00:04 445 Wednesday
16 2017-06-07 21:00:04 447 Wednesday
17 2017-06-07 20:00:04 445 Wednesday
18 2017-06-07 19:00:04 451 Wednesday
19 2017-06-07 18:00:04 469 Wednesday
20 2017-06-07 17:00:04 473 Wednesday
21 2017-06-07 16:00:03 510 Wednesday
22 2017-06-07 15:00:03 517 Wednesday
23 2017-06-07 14:00:03 524 Wednesday
24 2017-06-07 13:00:03 489 Wednesday
```

> So, how to prepare data to be able for combining the data frames?

I want the output to be like this example :

```
                  Date df1.Val df2.Val   Weekday
   2017-06-08 13:00:04 520              Thursday
   2017-06-08 12:00:00 507     507      Thursday
   2017-06-08 11:00:00 501     501      Thursday
   2017-06-08 10:00:00 472     472      Thursday
   2017-06-08 09:00:00 444     444      Thursday
   2017-06-08 08:00:00 446     446      Thursday
   2017-06-08 07:00:00 444     444      Thursday
   2017-06-08 06:00:00 441     441      Thursday
   2017-06-08 05:00:00 439     439      Thursday
   2017-06-08 04:00:00 442     442      Thursday
   2017-06-08 03:00:00 440     440      Thursday
   2017-06-08 02:00:00 443     443      Thursday
   2017-06-08 01:00:00 445     445      Thursday
   2017-06-08 00:00:00 445     445     Thursday
   2017-06-07 23:00:00 446     446     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 22:00:00 445     445     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 21:00:00 447     447     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 20:00:00 445     445     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 19:00:00 451     451     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 18:00:00 469     469     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 17:00:00 473     473     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 16:00:00 510     510     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 15:00:00 517     517     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 14:00:00 524     524     Wednesday
   2017-06-07 13:00:00         489     Wednesday
```

but these to Val are the same because the devices get val from the same source if they are from different sources assume it's going to be like this :

```
                  Date df1.Val df3.Val   Weekday
   2017-06-08 13:00:04 520     550      Thursday
   2017-06-08 12:00:00 507     515      Thursday
   2017-06-08 11:00:00 501     496      Thursday
```

Please help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now work. One caveat, the new dataframe is getting sorted automatically.:

```
Date = c("2017-06-08 13:00:04", "2017-06-08 12:00:04", "2017-06-08 11:00:04",
         "2017-06-08 10:00:04", "2017-06-08 09:00:04")
Val = c("520", "507", "501", "472", "444")
Weekday = c("Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday")

df1 = as.data.frame(cbind(Date, Val, Weekday))
df1$Date = as.POSIXct(df1$Date)
df1$Val = as.numeric(as.character(df1$Val))


Date1 = c("2017-06-08 12:00:04", "2017-06-08 11:00:04",
         "2017-06-08 10:00:04", "2017-06-08 09:00:04", "2017-06-08 09:00:03")
Val1 = c("507", "501", "472", "444", "446")
Weekday1 = c("Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday")

df2 = as.data.frame(cbind(Date1, Val1, Weekday1))
df2$Date1 = as.POSIXct(df2$Date1)
df2$Val1 = as.numeric(as.character(df2$Val1))

colnames(df2)[1] = "Date"
colnames(df2)[2] = "Val"
colnames(df2)[3] = "Weekday"

df1$Date = align.time(df1$Date, n = 60)
df2$Date = align.time(df2$Date, n = 60)

ndf = merge(df1, df2, by = c("Date", "Weekday"), all = TRUE, sort = TRUE)
ndf
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. The output are average value of 2 df but Date was chosen from only df1 I guess that because of different seconds and rows' date from df. edited :  
I'm gonna try but what package it is from?

Comment: I am having a difficulty with understanding the overall scope of your task. Can you clarify your point regarding the average outputs? The package is `xts`.

Comment: My bad so sorry. I want the output as Date (yy-mm-dd hh-mm)/ df1.val/ d2.val/ weekday and It's my first time asking in stack overflow I really don't how to explain very carefully. btw I will edit my post how the output should be.

Comment: Thank you so much at least it works for me of my example data but not on whole data I have to do data preparation more.